# Moving Web App from Netbeans to IntelliJ 10

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea, web-applications

... I have a web app started/developed with Netbeans and would like to move it to Intellij 10, but so far can't do it. Not easily at least. I tried to go the 'Create new project with existing sources' but that doesn't seem to work very well. IntelliJ is bungling the directory structure of the project.

That same project is also in a svn repository and I've not tried it yet, but would I have better luck checking out that project from svn in IntelliJ?

I guess manually copying over the existing dir structure manually over to an existing IntelliJ web project is an option, but that sounds like the last resort.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... checking out the project from svn did the trick. I eventually got the app running on Tomcat, but in all honesty, IntelliJ makes the whole process an ordeal compared to NetBeans. Now I remember why I stuck with NB for web dev.

However if there is a better/easier way to accomplish this, please chime in.

ps: once the project is checked out code change/commits are pretty seamless between both ides